# Making a mergesort in QTSpim

Tags: assembly, mergesort, qtspim

I have to write a merge sort for my class assignment in QTSpim. Still figuring out assembly and how much of a nightmare it is. I was hoping all my problems would be trying to get the subroutine to work, but i'm still having problems just storing inputs from the user.

I've written as many notes as I needed just to understand what I wrote myself, still have to write an output and run everything out of "main". I should be able to figure that out once I get past these few hurdles. Will take any help I can get, hoping to get better as the semester goes on.

**edit:

@Jester, yeah for sure, didnt want to write an essay so I kept it short, but it would be helpful to list the problems. Running the program line by line, it makes it to the store loop but would give me an error about 4-5 cycles through.

Exception occured at PC=0x004000d0
Unaligned address in inst/data fetch: 0x73656c62

My logic in the loop was to just have it cycle through and move the address up by 4 each time and just storing the user input into register 13. 
I thought it would be simple and I used the same method in my last assignment. Not sure whats different this time.

Im also questioning my logic when it comes to the sort as well, havent made it to the debugging of it yet since I'm stuck at the input, but was wondering if I could get some insight whether its the right approach or not.

And yes, after this assignment, I do plan on using the other register names. I think half the nightmare is just keeping track of which registers I used and where I used them. Thanks

```
    .data
    spacer:     .asciiz ", "                #used to make the output look nicer
    intro:      .asciiz "Enter the total number of inputs (must be a power of 2): "
    storeQuote: .asciiz "Enter the variables: "
    list2:      .word 0
    list:       .word 0
    .text
    .globl main

main:
    li      $v0, 4          #output intro
    la      $a0, intro
    syscall

    li      $v0, 5          #get input of size
    syscall

    add     $12, $v0, $zero     #storing total size in $12
    add     $8, $v0, $zero      #storing total size once again

    li      $v0, 4          #output prompt for user to input variables
    la      $a0, storeQuote
    syscall

    mul     $15, $12, -4    #multiplying for address value moved

    la      $13, list2
    la      $a0, spacer

store:
    li      $v0, 5          #get input of size
    syscall

    sw      $v0, 0($13)     #storing input to $13
    addi    $13, $13, 4     #moving pointer

    li      $v0, 4          #for formating on console
    syscall

    addi    $12, $12, -1    #loop counter subtraction
    bgt     $12, $v0, store #loop close 

main2:
    add     $13, $13, $15   #resetting pointer to zero
    addi    $14, $0, 4      #initial pointer move value for the loop
    addi    $24, $24, 1


firstloop:
    j       secondloop
    srl     $8, $8, 1       #diving total size by 2
    beq     $8, $24, fin    #if the set of lists is 1, jump to finish
    add     $9, $0, $8      #storing the loop counter for second loop
    sll     $15, $15, 2     #doubling the pointer move value for loop

secondloop:
    add     $14, $13, $8
    lw      $14, 0($14)
    jal     mergesub        #jump and link
    add     $13, $13, $15   #moving the pointer value
    addi    $9, $9, -1
    bnez    $9, secondloop
    j       firstloop

mergesub:
    lw      $10, 0($13)                     #loading a certain single variable from the array into a register to be compared
    lw      $11, 0($14)
    beq     $13, $16, function2             #used to end the loop if arrays have come to an end
    beq     $14, $17, function1
    beq     $10, $11, function1
    blt     $10, $11, function1             #the statements that determine if one variable in either array is less than
    bgt     $10, $11, function2             #the other and goes to its respective function to output

function1:
    beq     $13, $16, fin                   #part 2 of the check to see if the arrays are done
    sw      $10, 0($13)                     #storing the the lesser value into the output array
    addi    $13, $13, 4
    jr      $ra                             #goes back to loop

function2:
    beq     $14, $17, fin                   #does the same thing as function one but if the second array value was lesser
    sw      $11, 0($13)                     #value than the first array value
    addi    $14, $14, 4
    jr      $ra

fin:
    la      $v0, 10                         #ending the program
    syscall
```

Comment: Do not use numeric registers or you might mix them up with the named ones. Use your simulator to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. At the very least describe how it doesn't work.

Comment: What instruction is at `0x004000d0`?

Comment: `0x73656c62` looks like 4 ASCII characters that got used as a pointer.  Either one too many levels of dereferencing, or you have the problem Jester suggested: you used the same register for 2 different things via 2 different names for the same register.  Or some other problem.  Use the debugger to single-step.